# How to get the user Input from the alexa skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

When I ask something with the Alexa, it returns only the Intents and Entities based on the user input and I can't see the full user input.

Answer (score 1):

After reading a lot about Alexa Skill, I discovered that this can be achieved using a "dialog"

You need to have a custom intent that contains a slot type `AMAZON.SearchQuery`; no utterances need to be configured.
Your interaction model must have the intent, the dialog, and its prompts defined; it is important to define the prompt as elicitation.
Within the lambda, there will be two fundamental intents:

1. Handling the LaunchRequest,
2. Handling the customIntent.

What I did was that once the skill LaunchRequest is triggered, it delegates the conversation to customIntent but uses elicitation. This requires the user to fill in elicitation with a specific value that will be passed to the slot and can be retrieved from our custom intent. This implementation ultimately uses a type of recursion where customIntent calls itself

here's my iteration custom Intent definition , you can use UI to define it also except. "" I couldn't via UI

```
           {
            "name": "CustomIntent",
            "slots": [
                {
                    "name": "Query",
                    "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
                    "samples": [
                        "{Query}"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "samples": []
        }
```

here's  Dialog and promt

```
"dialog": {
    "intents": [
        {
            "name": "CustomIntent",
            "confirmationRequired": false,
            "prompts": {},
            "slots": [
                {
                    "name": "Query",
                    "type": "AMAZON.SearchQuery",
                    "confirmationRequired": false,
                    "elicitationRequired": true,
                    "prompts": {
                        "elicitation": "Elicit.Slot.1670425968761.1692305302317"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "delegationStrategy": "ALWAYS"
},
"prompts": [
    {
        "id": "Elicit.Slot.1670425968761.1692305302317",
        "variations": [
            {
                "type": "SSML",
                "value": "<speak></speak>"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

after this you only need modify your lambda code

```
class CustomIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Search query  Intent."""

    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("CustomIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response

        user_query = ask_utils.get_slot(handler_input, 'Query').value
        speak_output = user_query

        query_slot = Slot(
            name="Query",
            value="",
            confirmation_status=slot_confirmation_status.SlotConfirmationStatus.NONE
        )

        return (handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .add_directive(ElicitSlotDirective(updated_intent=Intent(name="CustomIntent",
                                                                         slots={"Query": query_slot},
                                                                         ),
                                                   slot_to_elicit='Query'))
                .ask("hi")
                .response)
```

and also similar the LaunchRequest

```
class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Skill Launch."""

    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool

        return ask_utils.is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response


        speak_output = f"Welcome skill message"

        
        query_slot = Slot(
                    name="Query",
                    value="",
                    confirmation_status=slot_confirmation_status.SlotConfirmationStatus.NONE
                )
    
        return (handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .add_directive(ElicitSlotDirective(updated_intent=Intent(name="CustomIntent",
                                                                         slots={"Query": query_slot},
                                                                         ),
                                                   slot_to_elicit='Query'))
                .ask("hi")
                .response)
```

hope this solution helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

**You will never get user's full speech**. However, you can use slots (both custom and predefined) to get parts of user speech.

`AMAZON.SearchQuery` and `AMAZON.LITERAL` slot types are the closest slots types that you should check.

Checkout the predefined set of slot types [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html)